# Data binding using jTtemplates with object

Tags: javascript, jtemplates

I have to access an object in my template, but the problem is the property which I am trying to access is having a space

```
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateResultsTable"> 
    {#template MAIN} 
    {$T.Asset Category}
</script>
```

If I am accessing the property without space it works `{$T.AssetCategory}`,but only when am trying to access `{$T.Asset Category}` it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try %20 for that space.. my suggestion is do not use space.. you can use '-' or '_' instead of space..

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside `{...}` is just JavaScript. You have to use bracket notation if property names are invalid identifiers:

```
{$T['Asset Category']}
```